# Jar File Does Not Run After IntelliJ Upgrade

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

## Expected

**Jar** file builds and runs with the following configuration described in the section [Generate Deployable JAR — Step 3 of 4](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-backend-app-as-an-android-engineer-49bd94b4c367) in this Medium post and outlined below.

1. Packaging the application in a JAR
   File: Project Structure > Project Settings > Artifacts > + > Jar > From modules with dependencies…

   - Module: projectModuleName_main
   - MainClass:YourMainClassWithMainMethod
   - Manifest: src/main/manifestName
   - Output directory: projectName/out/artifacts/jarName_jar
2. Build and run JAR

   - Build > Build Artifacts… > Action > Build
   - Run Jar: Run > Edit Configurations: + and select JAR Application (Before launch: + > Build Artifacts > artifactName)

## Observed

**Jar** file does not run after upgrading my version of IntelliJ.

**Error**

> Error: Unable to initialize main class Initialization
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/TypeCastException

**IntelliJ version**

> IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 (Community Edition)
>
> Build #IC-183.5153.38, built on January 9, 2019
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 x86_64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> Mac OS X 10.11.6

Comment: Out of curiosity can you ensure that the class `TypeCastException` is present in the jar?

Comment: I searched the project for `TypeCastException` and it did not come up with anything @PrashantZombade.

Comment: Okay. May be that is coming from some library/jar in your classpath. And looks like you your self found the solution. Congratulations!

Comment: Thank you @PrashantZombade! May you vote on the question/answer if you think this issue is valuable to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the existing **Jar** file and going through the steps outlined above *Packaging the application in a JAR File* and *Build and run JAR* resolved the issue. The new **Jar** is now running as expected.